# How to make a running Docker container aware of the other containers?

Tags: docker

I have a distributed service managed on a server that requires client IP address to be set in a configuration file.

For now, several client containers are started before the server, which is linked to the clients. This enables the server to retrieve their IP address from their name as described in its `/etc/hosts`. This information is then set in the configuration file. It works for a static infrastructure.

Since I want my infrastructure to be dynamic, I want to add new clients but I don't know how to make the server aware of the other containers since it seems impossible to set new configuration (I used `--link`) for a running container.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a service discovery tool - [etcd](https://coreos.com/using-coreos/etcd/) and [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) are popular options for this use case.

Comment: And something like registrator which will publish them.  https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator